# TAB Folding Console Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, debugging, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin that allows you to fold lines starting with a tab. For debugging purposes in a hierarchy of classes, I put a number of tabs in front of each line depending on its depth since the first toString(nl) call.

each time I have this kind of structure

```
        public String toString(String nl) {
        ...
        String nnl = nl + "\t";
        controlledClass.toString(nnl);
        ...
        }
```

So now I have several pages of debug info and need to quickly manage it. If I could fold specific parts of the ouput, it would save me lots of parsing time.

Answer (score 0):

Start using an actual logging framework such as [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) / [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and work with log-levels:
It'll make everything more manageable, rather then finding a short-term solution to parsing tab-depths..

Comment: I know about those frameworks but don't want. They have become a gas factory (that is a wonderfully complicated solution). Here in J2ME debugging, I just need tab folding while browsing the output. So by default I see everything. then while browsing the console I fold some tab levels.

Comment: Ok, thats a valid point.. Don't know of a ready made solution right now.